# How to create dynamic responsive four columns to two columns with borders

Tags: css

I'm creating a responsive website with four columns.

[image]

So when the page gets smaller then it will turn into two columns then the `border-right` style of the second element will be removed and so on. My main problem here is how can I target the columns or the elements without using hard coded style for that element, for example:

```
   /* don't want to use this since it'll be dynamic list*/
   #spring-vet-inner .sv-list:nth(2) { clear:both; }
```

Since i'll be putting the content in `custom_types` with **wordpress** so I'll be inserting multiple list of data like so. Here is my [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/leonardeveloper/ewm505h2/).

Comment: If you want a pure CSS solution, you will have to use nth-child. There is no other way with pure CSS.

Comment: Should I change my html structure for that? How about if I use javascript or jquery? Any work arounds?

Comment: You could use some JS, but you can do it with pure CSS :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `:nth-child(4n+1)` to target every 5th element, to do your clearing.

Then you can use `:nth-child(4n)` to remove the border on every 4th element.

This way, in terms of styling, it doesn't matter how many items you have.

You can also improve the widths for better responsiveness and a more mobile-first approach. Instead of a hard coded width you can use percentages. Eg:

```
#spring-vet-inner .sv-list { 
    float:left; 
    width:50%; 
}

@media (min-width:768px){
    #spring-vet-inner .sv-list {
        width:25%;
        min-height:250px;
        border-right:solid 1px #000
    }
    #spring-vet-inner .sv-list:nth-child(4n) {
        border-right:0 none;
    }
    #spring-vet-inner .sv-list:nth-child(4n+1) {
        border-right-color:red;
        clear:both;
    }
}
```

You could also maybe add a parent `max-width` for desktop.

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/cb162Lwv/4/)

[JSFiddle full screen](http://jsfiddle.net/cb162Lwv/4/show/) (just add '/show' to the end of the URL)

Comment: i like your answer better. mine was a quick fix on his code.. +1

Comment: If the column is two then maybe the `border-right` will still remain in the element. So can I use `.sv-list:nth-child(odd)` in there?

Comment: Yes you could do, then remove it after a certain breakpoint if you like: `sv-list:nth-child(odd){border-right:solid 1px #BADA55; }   @media (min-width:768px){ sv-list:nth-child(odd){border:0 none;} }`

Comment: @TonyBarnes Lastly how can I center the content if I only have one .sv-list?

Comment: @TonyBarnes My main problem now is what if I have 3 `.sv-list` items or 1 since it's dynamic content. How can I fix the borders?

Comment: @LeonardDrapeza Well, this is outside of the original question. If you want to target different amounts of items, it would be best to wrap some columns into rows - so for every 4 columns, wrap it in a html row. Then you could use `:last-child {}` to target the last item in each row, to remove the border you don't want.

Comment: @LeonardDrapeza To center the items, you'll need to use `display:inline-block; vertical-align:top;` for each item, instead of a `float:left;`, and then add a `text-align:center;` to the parent wrapper :)

Answer (score 0):

<del>You can use `:nth-child(even)`</del>

<del>As the 2nd and 4th columns will always be "even", this way you can tell them to remove `border-right`.</del>

---

UPDATE :

Here is the update on how to do for more than 4 Items :

```
#spring-vet-inner .sv-list:nth-child(4n+4) {
    border-right:none;
}
#spring-vet-inner .sv-list:nth-child(4n+5) {
    clear:both;
}
@media screen and (max-width: 818px) {
    #spring-vet-inner .sv-list:nth-child(2n+2) {
        border-right:none;
    }
    #spring-vet-inner .sv-list:nth-child(2n+3) {
        clear:both;
    }
}
```

Try resizing the browser in this [Live Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/85u7yx7m/4/)

Comment: How about if I have this html code https://jsfiddle.net/leonardeveloper/3d690sg0/3/ since the data will be dynamic and have multiple `.sv-list` how can I determine the 4th or 8th element and so on to remove the `border-right` style?

Comment: 2, 4 ,6, 8, 10, 12... will always be taken in account with `:nth-child(even)`. The only matter that remains is to determine which max-width screen you want to focus for this.

Comment: Yes but if it is in full width the `border-right` style of the 2nd , 6th element will be remove also (since they are even numbers). I just want to remove the `border-right` style of the last element which is incremented by 4,8 and so on.

Answer (score 0):

If you need to support only modern browsers, use media query to identify when the screen is small. 
For example, i see that your columns are each 200px wide with 1px border to the right. So the width below which the layout needs to become a 2 column layout would be the width of 4 columns = (200 + 1 + 200 + 1 + 200 + 1 + 200 + extra for body padding) = 803px + 12px = 815px

the css would then become:

```
@media screen and (max-width: 815px) {
  #spring-vet-inner .sv-list{ width:49%;}
  #spring-vet-inner .sv-list:nth-child(odd){clear:both;}
  #spring-vet-inner .sv-list:nth-child(even){ border-right:none;}
}
```

width is set to 49% so that it takes the whole row, and odd and even elements are used as they are multiples of 2.

[update your code in jsFiddle Link](https://jsfiddle.net/ewm505h2/1/)
hope this helps.